# How to avoid the silent tickeling noises when streaming sound from microphone to speakers using DirectSound and C#?

Tags: c#, .net, directx, noise, directsound

I try to *stream sound samples* from my *microphone* to my *speakers* by using **DirectSound** and **C#**. It should be similar to 'listening to microphone', but later I want to use this for something else. By testing my approach I've noticed *silent tickeling, cracking noises* in the background. I would guess this has something to do with the delay between writing and playing the buffer, which must be greater than the latency to write the chunks.

If I set the delay between recording and playout to less than 50ms. Mostly it works but sometimes I get really *loud cracking noises*. So I've decided to a delay about at least 50ms. This works okay for me, but the delay of the systems "listen to device" seems to be much shorter. I would guess it is about 15-30ms, and nearly not noticeable. For 50ms I get at least a little reverb effect.

In the following I'll show you my ***microphone*** code (partially):
The initialisation is done like this:

```
        capture = new Capture(device);

        // Creating the buffer
        // Determining the buffer size
        bufferSize = format.AverageBytesPerSecond * bufferLength / 1000;
        while (bufferSize % format.BlockAlign != 0) bufferSize += 1;
        chunkSize = Math.Max(bufferSize, 256); 
        bufferSize = chunkSize * BUFFER_CHUNKS;
        this.bufferLength = chunkSize * 1000 / format.AverageBytesPerSecond; // Redetermining the buffer Length that will be used.

        captureBufferDescription = new CaptureBufferDescription();
        captureBufferDescription.BufferBytes = bufferSize;
        captureBufferDescription.Format = format;
        captureBuffer = new CaptureBuffer(captureBufferDescription, capture);

        // Creating Buffer control           
        bufferARE = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        // Adding notifier to buffer.
        bufferNotify = new Notify(captureBuffer);
        BufferPositionNotify[] bpns = new BufferPositionNotify[BUFFER_CHUNKS];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < BUFFER_CHUNKS ; i ++) bpns[i] =    new BufferPositionNotify() { Offset = chunkSize * (i+1) - 1, EventNotifyHandle = bufferARE.SafeWaitHandle.DangerousGetHandle() };
        bufferNotify.SetNotificationPositions(bpns);
```

The capturing will run like this in an extra thread:

```
        // Initializing
        MemoryStream tempBuffer = new MemoryStream();

        // Capturing
        while (isCapturing && captureBuffer.Capturing)
        {
            bufferARE.WaitOne();
            if (isCapturing && captureBuffer.Capturing)
            {
                captureBuffer.Read(currentBufferPart * chunkSize, tempBuffer, chunkSize, LockFlag.None);
                ReportChunk(applyVolume(tempBuffer.GetBuffer()));
                currentBufferPart = (currentBufferPart + 1) % BUFFER_CHUNKS;
                tempBuffer.Dispose();
                tempBuffer = new MemoryStream(); // Reset Buffer;
            }
        }

        // Finalizing
        isCapturing = false;
        tempBuffer.Dispose();
        captureBuffer.Stop();
        if (bufferARE.WaitOne(bufferLength + 1)) currentBufferPart = (currentBufferPart + 1) % BUFFER_CHUNKS; // That on next start the correct bufferpart will be read.
        stateControlARE.Set();
```

While capturing `ReportChunk` takes the data to the speaker as an event that could be subscribed. The ***speaker*** part is initialized like this:

```
        // Creating the dxdevice.
        dxdevice = new Device(device);
        dxdevice.SetCooperativeLevel(hWnd, CooperativeLevel.Normal);

        // Creating the buffer
        bufferDescription = new BufferDescription();
        bufferDescription.BufferBytes = bufferSize;
        bufferDescription.Format = input.Format;
        bufferDescription.ControlVolume = true;

        bufferDescription.GlobalFocus = true; // That sound doesn't stop if the hWnd looses focus.
        bufferDescription.StickyFocus = true; // - " -
        buffer = new SecondaryBuffer(bufferDescription, dxdevice);
        chunkQueue = new Queue<byte[]>();

        // Creating buffer control
        bufferARE = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        // Register at input device
        input.ChunkCaptured += new AInput.ReportBuffer(input_ChunkCaptured);
```

The data is put by the event method into the queue, simply by:

```
        chunkQueue.Enqueue(buffer);
        bufferARE.Set();
```

Filling the playbackbuffer and starting/stopping the playback buffer is done by another thread:

```
        // Initializing
        int wp = 0;
        bufferARE.WaitOne(); // wait for first chunk

        // Playing / writing data to play buffer.
        while (isPlaying)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            bufferARE.WaitOne(BufferLength * 3); // If a chunk is played and there is no new chunk we try to continue and may stop playing, else may the buffer runs out. 
            // Note that this may fails if the sender was interrupted within one chunk
            if (isPlaying)
            {
                if (chunkQueue.Count > 0)
                {
                    while (chunkQueue.Count > 0) wp = writeToBuffer(chunkQueue.Dequeue(), wp);
                    if (buffer.PlayPosition > wp - chunkSize * 3 / 2) buffer.SetCurrentPosition(((wp - chunkSize * 2 + bufferSize) % bufferSize));
                    if (!buffer.Status.Playing)
                    {
                        buffer.SetCurrentPosition(((wp - chunkSize * 2 + bufferSize) % bufferSize));    // We have 2 chunks buffered so we step back 2 chunks and play them while getting new chunks.
                        buffer.Play(0, BufferPlayFlags.Looping);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    buffer.Stop();
                    bufferARE.WaitOne(); // wait for a filling chunk
                }
            }
        }

        // Finalizing
        isPlaying = false;
        buffer.Stop();
        stateControlARE.Set();
```

`writeToBuffer` simply writes the enqueued chunk to the buffer by `this.buffer.Write(wp, data, LockFlag.None);` and caring about `bufferSize` and `chunkSize` and `wp`, which represents the last writing position. I think this is everything that is important about my code. Maybe the definitions are missing and at least there is another method that starts/stops=controls the threads.

I've posted this code in case I've made a mistake in filling the buffer or my initialisation is wrong. But I would guess that this problem occurs because the execution of C# bytecode is too slow or something like that. But in the end my question is still open: **My question is how to reduce the latency and how to avoid noises that shouldn't be there?**

Comment: PC inputs tend to be noisy, especially for on-board audio hardware. The audio chip is usually some distance away from the actual jacks and the traces on the motherboard pick up all kinds of noise. This noise is unavoidable, as it's a physical problem, not something caused by software.

Comment: The simple whitenoise you are talking about isn't my problem. My problem is the sometimes occuring silent cracking. This doesn't occur when I use 'listen to device' in my systems settings.

Comment: How are you defining "silent"?

Comment: There is something "noticeable": I would compare it to someone who is some meters away from the microphone and closing slowly a zipper, so that you sometimes hear the cracking of it. This noise isn't dominant but if you try to listen to it you'll hear it. Especially it occurs if I talk aloud and I'm near overmodulation.

Answer (score 1):

I know the reason of your problem and the way that you can solve it, but I can't implement it in C# and .Net, so I will explain it in hope that you can find your way.

Audio will be recorded by your mic. with an specified frequency( for example 44100 ) and then played on the sound card at same sample rate( again 44100 ), the problem is the crystal that count the time in input device( mic. for example ) is not same as the crystal that play sound in sound card.
also the difference is so small they are not the same( there is no 2 exact same crystal in entire world ) so after a while there will be a gap in your playback routines.

Now the solution is re-sample data to match the sample rate of the output but I don't know how to do that in C# and .Net

Comment: I've heard about that, but as far as I know this should be solved by the sound card driver or at least by directx. Nobody would notice a single missing sample if it is filled with a zero. By the way since this question was asked about a year ago, I've already found the answer and I will add it.

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago I figured out, that this problem was caused by the `Thread.Sleep(1);` in combination with high CPU usage. Due the windows timerresolution is 15,6ms by default, this sleep doesn't mean sleep for 1ms, but sleep until the next clock interrupt is reached. (For more read [this paper](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/0/2/3027D574-C433-412A-A8B6-5E0A75D5B237/Timer-Resolution.docx)) Combined with high CPU usage it may stacks up to the length of a chunk or even more.

*For example:* If my chunksize is 40ms, this could be about 46,8ms (3 * 15,6ms) and this causes the tickeling. One solution for that is setting the resolution down to 1ms. That can be done in this way:

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint="timeBeginPeriod", SetLastError=true)]
private static extern uint timeBeginPeriod(uint uiPeriod);

[DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint="timeEndPeriod", SetLastError=true)]
private static extern uint timeEndPeriod(uint uiPeriod);

void routine()
{
   Thead.Sleep(1); // May takes about 15,6ms or even longer.
   timeBeginPeriod(1); // Should be set at the startup of the application.
   Thead.Sleep(1); // May takes about 1, 2 or 3 ms depending on the CPU usage.

   // ... time depending routines goes here ...

   timeEndPeriod(1); // Should end at application shutdown.
}
```

As far as I know this should be already done by directx. But due this setting is a global setting, other parts of the application or other applications maybe change it. This shouldn't happen if an application sets and revokes the setting once. But somehow it seems to happen caused by any dirty programmed part or other running application.

One more thing that needs to be watched, is whether you're still using the correct position of the directx buffer, if you're skipping one chunk for any reason. In this case a resynchronization is required.